# Express vs NestJS project structure

Tags: node.js, react-native, rest, express, nestjs

I am planning to build a rest api in node that will be consumed by a react-native mobile app(using JWT tokens) and reactJS web app(admin UI using sessions/http-only cookies). Would you advise me to write this directly in express or use a framework like nestJS?

1. How should I structure/architect the project to meet the above requirements taking into consideration, ease of Management, autoscaling, hosting, etc?
2. Would you consider dockerizing the node application over running node directly on the server? is there any performance gains?
3. should I break the project into 3 repos ie:
4. ```
   rest api | backend webUI(reactJS) | mobile app (react-native)
   ```
5. ```
   or
   ```
6. ```
   rest api + backend webUI(reactJS) | mobile app (react-native)
   ```

Ideas/advises are welcome please, thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer based on my work experience in both:

1. Structure/architecture of the project depends if you are working alone on the API or in teams (express gives you freedom in code however you like but it's a nightmare if your application grows and gets bigger in complexity with a big team trying to maintain it), NestJS has a structure to follow for you and your team (if MVC model gets the job done for your use case)
2. Docker use is for ease of deployment for both (if you know what you are doing) and can have better performance when running multiple instances. the catch is in the production server with a docker database backup and recovery are harder and if you need migration/restructure after deployment in prod welp...you gonna cry
3. I always separate  (API | web UI | mobile app) so I can debug them easily separate domains of errors but talk to your team and provide docs for what they want in the Rest service if you are alone and the WebUI is not exposed to the same user base as the mobile app then it doesn't matter really